# Why can't I put keyboard focus on "Notify [my email] daily of any new answers"?

Tags: feature-request, usability, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pressing TAB after the “Tags” textbox on Ask Question page should jump to the checkbox underneath](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61841/pressing-tab-after-the-tags-textbox-on-ask-question-page-should-jump-to-the-che)

It's very important for me to use my computer's mouse as little as possible. I use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go between form elements. But for some reason I can't <kbd>Tab</kbd> into the checkbox of "Notify [my email] daily of any new answers". When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, focus just skips the checkbox and jumps to the "Post Your Question" button.

Why is this? Can this be solved?

Comment: You can... it's just much later in the tab order than you would expect.  Quick experiment later: it takes 18 tabs to go from the Tags field to the checkbox.